# Firebase Child Path Not Recognized

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a child that I append to a ref. When I try to add a listener to the usersRef with the uid, the listener doesn't listen to the child, only the root. When I print the child out only the root database info prints out.

```
path- https://.....-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users
```

Why isn't the child recognized? This is happening for both iOS and Android.

iOS

```swift
var usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    usersRef.child(uid)
    
    let path = usersRef.description()
    print("path- \(path)")

    query = usersRef.queryOrderedByKey()

    listenerRefHandle = query?.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    }
}
```

Android

```kotlin
var usersRef = Firebase.database.reference.child("users")

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid?.let { uid ->
        usersRef.child(uid)

        val path = usersRef.toString().substring(usersRef.root.toString().length-1)
        println("path- $path")

        query = usersRef

        listenerRefHandle = query?.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
        }
    }
}
```

If I do it this way, they both work fine, but the problem is I have to force unwrap the uids.

```
var usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)

var usersRef = Firebase.database.reference.child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance()!!.uid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code doesn't do anything in both Swift and Kotlin:

```
usersRef.child(uid)
```

It builds a reference to the child `uid`, but doesn't assign the resulting reference to anything.

If you want to use the reference that you build, assign it to a variable:

```swift
let userRef = usersRef.child(uid)
```

```kotlin
val userRef = usersRef.child(uid)
```